# Is CC-BY 4.0 attribution recursive?

Tags: license-notice, license, cc-by

Let's say we have Work A licensed under CC-BY 4.0, made by Author A.

Author B uses Work A to create Work B, attributing Work A: "Work A was created by Author A under the CC-BY 4.0 license (link to work A here). Work B is also under the CC-BY 4.0 license."

Now Author C comes along and wants to use Work B to create Work C. Do they need to attribute Author A as well as Author B? Or do they only need to attribute Author B?

Option 1, non-recursive: "Work B was created by Author B under the CC-BY 4.0 license (link to work B here). Work C is also under the CC-BY 4.0 license."

Option 2, recursive: "Work A was created by Author A under the CC-BY 4.0 license (link to work A here). Work B was created by Author B under the CC-BY 4.0 license (link to work B here). Work C is also under the CC-BY 4.0 license."

## My own research

This is the relevant legal code:

```
Attribution.

    If You Share the Licensed Material (including in modified form), You must:
        retain the following if it is supplied by the Licensor with the Licensed Material:
            identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material and any others designated to receive attribution, in any reasonable manner requested by the Licensor (including by pseudonym if designated);
            a copyright notice;
            a notice that refers to this Public License;
            a notice that refers to the disclaimer of warranties;
            a URI or hyperlink to the Licensed Material to the extent reasonably practicable;
        indicate if You modified the Licensed Material and retain an indication of any previous modifications; and
        indicate the Licensed Material is licensed under this Public License, and include the text of, or the URI or hyperlink to, this Public License.
```

In particular, "identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material and **any others designated to receive attribution**, in any reasonable manner requested by the Licensor".

Who are "any others designated to receive attribution"? What if the Licensor does not request anything other than licensing their work under CC-BY 4.0?

Comment: Note to avoid confusion: It is not necessary for C to license their work under CC-BY; by attributing to A,B they have complied with the license conditions, and may license their own contribution however they like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that by "*Author B uses Work A to create Work B*" you mean that Author B makes work B which is a copyright derivative of work A.  Work C, then, is then a copyright derivative of both works B and A.  Authors A, B, and C are rightsholders in this work, and C will be violating A and B's copyrights if (s)he distributes this work without a licence to do so from both A and B.

Fortunately, A and B have both granted such a licence, by publishing their works under CC BY 4.0, provided C attributes them both as described above.